# How to get the width of troika-three-text object

Tags: javascript, three.js

How do I get the width and height of a troika-three-text Text object?

```
import { Text } from 'troika-three-text'

// Create:
const myText = new Text()
myScene.add(myText)

// Set properties to configure:
myText.text = 'Hello world!'
myText.fontSize = 0.2
myText.position.z = -2
myText.color = 0x9966FF

// Update the rendering:
myText.sync()
```

Comment: Hi, I know that `Text()` objects are `Object3D()`. I tried scaling using `myText .scale.set(2, 2, 2)` and it works if that's what you need. However, `let boundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(text)`, won't work. It gives me an Infinite size.

Comment: @cconsta1 it will be -Infinity because the value hasn't been computed yet. Call `sync()` first and then wait for the `synccomplete` event to fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

```
getWidthHeight() {
    const size = new THREE.Vector3()
    this.text.geometry.boundingBox.getSize(size)
    return { width: size.x, height: size.y }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to make it work is to read the values once they've been computed. This can be done by waiting for the [`synccomplete`](https://protectwise.github.io/troika/troika-three-text/#handling-asynchronous-updates) event to fire:

```js
myText.addEventListener("synccomplete", () => {
  const width = text.geometry.boundingBox.max.x - text.geometry.boundingBox.min.x;
  // ...
});
```